# JSch - Problems with session.connect()

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

At the moment I'm working on a Java program to monitor our UNIX scripts. The problem is that we get a new server next week and I have to change my program, so it could connect to the new machine, using JSch.
Currently I'm using this way to get a connection to the old servers:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(user, host);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setTimeout(60000);
session.connect();
```

While testing it on the new server, i got the problem, that it would stop at `session.connect()` and won't go any further.
After some research i found out, that the JSch lib i was using, was to old for the new OpenSSH Version from the Server, so I upgraded my JSch to version 0.1.54, but even that won't kill the problem.
Actual I'm trying to use SSH-Keys for this, but the problem is still the same, no stacktrace, nothing. Here is the actual code I try to get running:

```
String private_key = "path_to_file";
jsch.addIdentity(private_key);
session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setTimeout(60000);
session.connect();
```

Keys:
`SSH-2 RSA`

Client:
`JRE 1.8.0_112<br>`
`JSch 0.1.54`

Server:
`OpenSSH 7.2p2<br>`
`OpenSSL 1.0.2g`

**With this configuration on the Server it's working**:
OpenSSH 6.6.1p1
OpenSSL 1.0.1f

**EDIT** 
Adding

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
```

Solved the Problem for me

Comment: Instead of adding the solved in the question add your solution in the answer and mark it accepted..

Comment: Thanks, I will mark my answer tomorrow, can't do it now. And I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
```

Solved the Problem for me

Answer (score 0):

This block of code for me if we pass the password:

```
test(){
Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session = jsch.getSession(username, hostip, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
}
```